# Zsh - dnf autocompletion

Tags: fedora, zsh, autocomplete

Since Fedora will use `dnf` as default package manager in its next release, is there available autocompletion for zsh/oh-my-zsh/zpretzo?

If not, is there somebody willing to do it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a work around :

```
cp /usr/share/zsh/5.0.7/functions/_yum /usr/share/zsh/5.0.7/functions/_dnf
```

then :

```
vi /usr/share/zsh/5.0.7/functions/_dnf
```

and under vim type:

```
:%s/yum/dnf/g
```

save and exit vim ( type :x and Enter)
relog under zsh and enjoy.
[via](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/2452)

Comment: Well, that's certainly an option :D Recently a zsh [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) got a [dnf module](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules/dnf) so  there is no need anymore. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Until there is a proper completion module for dnf, you can use yum completion. Just add this simple line into your zshrc:

```
compdef dnf=yum
```

This line must be placed anywhere after completion initialization.

Answer (score 1):

My zsh (5.1) already has support for dnf:

```
% rpm -qf /usr/share/zsh//5.1/functions/_dnf
zsh-5.1-1.fc24.x86_64
```

Comment: True; but I experience that the functions defined there do not complete a package name. The solution provided in another post (````compdef dnf=yum````) slove this.